# How to swap strings in multiline

Tags: awk, sed, perl

tldr; How can I swap the account and remove the minus sign

The file contains multiple transactions like this

Input:

```
2018/01/08 * Aldi
    ; MD5Sum: a587a267588505265ae437c43c978886
    ; CSV: 2018-1-8,aldi,40.85
    Expenses:Groceries
    Expenses:Unknown                                USD -40.85
    ; :Groceries:
```

Expected output:

```
2018/01/08 * Aldi
    ; MD5Sum: a587a267588505265ae437c43c978886
    ; CSV: 2018-1-8,aldi,40.85
    Expenses:Groceries                              USD 40.85 
    Expenses:Unknown                                
    ; :Groceries:
```

Note that the amount at the far right has been negated and that it is attached to `Expenses:Groceries` rather than to `Expenses:Unknown`.

Comment: What are the accounts that should be swapped in the other transactions? Is it always the same?

Comment: @Kusalananda Always remove the amount from 'Expenses:Unknown'. Always add the amount to 'Expenses:AnyOtherThanUnknown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using perl the easiest way is to read all the data in at once, split it into stanzas presumably beginning with 4 digits at the start of a line, then operate on each stanza separately. 
Assumptions are made on the data as they aren't fully specified in the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $data = join("", <>);
my @stanzas = split(/^(?=\d{4})/m, $data);
foreach my $st (@stanzas){
 if($st =~ m/Expenses:(?!Unknown)\S+\s*$/m){
  if($st =~ m/Expenses:Unknown\s+(USD\s+-[0-9.]+)/){
     my $amount = $1; 
     $amount =~ s/-//;
     $st =~ s/Expenses:(?!Unknown)(\S+)(\s*)$/Expenses:$1                              $amount/m;
     $st =~ s/Expenses:Unknown(\s+USD\s+-[0-9.]+)/Expenses:Unknown/;
  }
 }
}
print join("", @stanzas);
```

Here the `split()` function uses a look-ahead pattern `(?=)` to split the whole input on lines with 4 digits at the start.

For each stanza, if it has Expenses not followed by Unknown followed by non-spaces and then spaces only, and Unknown followed by a negative number, the number and its preceding USD is captured, and the minus removed.

The result is substituted into the first matched line, with some fixed amount of space, and removed from the Unknown line. Doing this separately allows for these two fields to be in a different order in the stanza.

Finally, the stanzas are concatenated and printed.

Comment: Thank you very much. What other information may I provide to improve my question?

Comment: For example, you have just added an important detail to the comments, which changes the necessary code. I've updated my answer. If it fits your question don't forget to accept the answer, and perhaps elaborate further problems in later questions. It is best to keep a single well-defined problem per question, as it more likely to attract answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl in paragraph mode we will process a paragraph at a time and extract the expenses in us dollar from unknown field and stick it in the other expenses line:

```
$ perl -p00 -e '
    my @A = /^\h+Expenses:Unknown(\h+USD\h+)-(\d+\.\d+)$/m;

    s/^\h+Expenses:\K((Unknown)\h|\S+).*$/$2 ? $2 : "$1@A"/gem if @A;
' file
```